# Очистка Standby List C# winforms net.fraim 4.7.x

Tags: c#, winforms

Не могу реализовать очистку Standby List'a по кнопке, хочу чтобы запускался цикл очистки каждую минуту, но не могу найти нормальной документации и верных решений.

Comment: Может это поможет? https://www.white-windows.ru/kak-bystro-ochistit-pamyat-v-windows-10-pri-ee-vnezapnom-zapolnenii/

Comment: Для меня это не подходит, мне нужно это сделать в коде программы